# How to get deleted YouTube videos and subscribers?

Tags: youtube

I followed the link https://youtu.be/GezcSLUZvkI for update my channel to brand channel. My channel videos and subscribers deleted by mistake during try to make my channel Branding,, how to revert by videos and subscribers?

Comment: And this has what to do with programming?

Comment: Just for help? If wrong pls let me Know what is the correct platform to post?